# Calcular a média entre 3 datas direto no banco sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2005

Qual a maneira mais eficiente de calcular a média de datas em uma mesma coluna pelo banco sqlserver? Preciso pegar a data das 3 últimas vendas de um cliente, e retornar em dias para saber se esse cliente compra, por exemplo, de 30 em 30 dias, 60 em 60 etc.

Eu fiz a seguinte query:

```
SELECT TOP 3 data 
FROM dbo.tab_venda ven INNER JOIN 
dbo.tab_item_venda iven ON iven.num_venda = ven.num_venda 
WHERE ven.cod_pessoa = 737 AND iven.cod_produto = 2111 
ORDER BY ven.data DESC
```

que me retorna:

```
2015-08-10 00:00:00.000 
2015-07-10 00:00:00.000 
2015-06-03 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Mostre uma tabela para nós com os campos.

Comment: Eu fiz a seguinte query:
SELECT TOP 3 data 
FROM   dbo.tab_venda ven 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tab_item_venda iven 
               ON iven.num_venda = ven.num_venda 
WHERE  ven.cod_pessoa = 737 
       AND iven.cod_produto = 2111 
ORDER  BY ven.data DESC 

que me retorna:
DATA
2015-08-10 00:00:00.000
2015-07-10 00:00:00.000
2015-06-03 00:00:00.000

Comment: Você nao precisa da média, pelo o que entendi. Você precisa da diferenca de dias entre as tres ultimas datas, correto?

Comment: Sim, isso, mas coloquei como média porque eu preciso pegar o intervalo entre as datas, por exemplo: Entre a data 03/06/2015 as 10/07/2015 é igual a 37 e entre 10/07/2015 a 10/05/2015 igual 30, faço a soma desse intervalo que da 67 e divido por 2 (pois são dois intervalos, acredito eu) onde o valor final seria 33,5 então vou considerar que meu cliente costuma a compra de 33 em 33 dias.. Esse ta sendo o meu raciocínio né.. Se alguém achar que esta incorreto por favor me ajudar. Agora queria fazer isso tudo via banco, será que da certo?

Comment: @LaísaFerreiraCardoso, atualizei a minha resposta. Creio que agora está fazendo o que você deseja. Troque os campos para os do seu modelo e teste, por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O SQL abaixo realiza a operação solicitada. Ele faz a média de dias entre as datas das últimas três compras, chamadas aqui de A,B,C. Sendo A a mais antiga das três e C a mais recente das três.

```
select
    client_report_id,   
    datediff(dd,A,B) DIFF_A_B,
    datediff(dd,B,C) DIFF_B_C,
    (datediff(dd,A,B) + datediff(dd,B,C))/2 media,
    A,
    B,
    C
from    
(
    SELECT  
        client_report_id,
        max(case when rownum = 3 then received_date end) A,
        max(case when rownum = 2 then received_date end) B,
        max(case when rownum = 1 then received_date end) C
    FROM
     (
        SELECT  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY client_report_id ORDER BY client_report_id,received_date desc) AS rownum, 
            client_report_id,
            received_date
        FROM
            receipt
    ) A
    WHERE A.rownum IN (1,2,3)
    group by client_report_id
) B
WHERE A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NOT NULL AND C IS NOT NULL
```

Note que esse SQL realiza o cálculo para todos os registros do banco, não apenas para um específico, como o exibido na pergunta.

O retorno dele consiste do ID do Cliente e 6 campos. Os necessários são apenas o id do cliente e o campo media. Porém, deixei os outros para que fique claro a conta que está sendo feita.

Para ele funcionar, assume-se que o cliente fez, no mínimo, 3 compras. Se ele fizer menos do que isso, então não aparecerá.

Veja que, embora o nome da tabela e campos não reflita o da pergunta, é muito simples alterá-lo, já que se trata apenas de uma tabela (Receipt) e dois campos (client_report_id e received_date).

Comment: Perfeito! Adaptei ao meu código e deu certo! Muito obrigada.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se com o **AVG** (Average - Média) funciona.

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, AVG(CONVERT(FLOAT, data))) as [MediaData] 
FROM 
    dbo.tab_venda ven 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tab_item_venda iven ON iven.num_venda = ven.num_venda 
WHERE 
    ven.cod_pessoa = 737 AND iven.cod_produto = 2111 
ORDER BY 
    ven.data 
DESC
```

Comment: Eu tentei o AVG da um erro por conta do ORDER BY: 
Column "dbo.tab_venda.DATA" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Partindo do principio que sua tabela contenha uma chave primária:

```
select 
  sum(c.diff)/2 as total
from vendas v1
inner join (select top 3 id, data from vendas order by data desc) v2
  on v2.id = v1.id-1
cross apply (
  select datediff(d,v2.data,v1.data) as diff
) c
```

Veja exemplo funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5caf85/5/0).